# Matrix chain multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am reading Thoman Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms" and I have problems understanding the algorithm written below.

```
        Matrix-Chain-Order(p)
        1 n ← length[p] − 1
        2 for i ← 1 to n
        3     do m[i, i] ← 0
        4     for l ← 2 to n                     //l is the chain length.
        5         do for i ← 1 to n − l + 1      // what is this?
        6                do j ← i + l − 1        // what is this?
        7                   m[i, j] ← ∞
        8                   for k ← i to j − 1
        9                       do q ← m[i, k] + m[k + 1, j] + pi−1pkpj
       10                          if q < m[i, j]
       11                            then m[i, j] ← q
       12                                s[i, j] ← k
       13 return m and s
```

Now, I know how the algorithm works. I know how to proceed in constructing the table and all that. In other words I know what happens up to line 4 and I also know what 9 to 13 is about.
I have problems understanding the subtleties of the "for" loops though. Lines 4 to 8 are difficult to understand. In line 5 why does i go up to n-l+1 and why is j in line 6 set to i+l-1. In line 7  ,m[i, j] is initialized  for the comparison in line 10 but then again line 8 is a mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just going through the algorithm definition on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) and it's pretty comprehensive there. I'll try to explain you how I understood the solution.

The crux of the problem is we are basically trying to 'parenthesise' i.e. prioritize how we chain our matrices so that they are multiplied most efficiently and it's reflected in this line of code:

```
q = m[i,k] + m[k+1,j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
```

To understand the above stand, first let's establish that `i` and `j` are fixed here i.e. we are trying to compute m[i,j] or the most efficient way to multiply matrices `A[i..j]` and `k` is the variable.

So at a very high level if `i=1` and `j=3` and the matrices are :

```
(A*B)*C //We are trying to establish where the outer most parenthesis should be
```

We don't know where it should be, hence we try all possibilities and pick the combination where `m[i,j]` is minimized. So we try:

```
i=1 and j=3
A*(B*C) //k=1
(A*B)*C //k=2
```

So clearly `k` should vary from `i` to `j-1` which is reflected in the loop as we try all possible combinations and take the most efficient one. So for any `k` we'll have two partitions: `A[i..k]` and `A[k+1...j]`

So the cost of multiplication of A[i..j] for this partition of `k` is:

```
 m[i,k]  //Minimum cost of multiplication of A[i..k]

 m[k+1,j] //Minimum cost of multiplication of A[k+1..j]

 p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j]; //Final cost of multiplying the two partitions i.e. A[i..k] and A[k+1..j], where p contains the dimensions of the matrices.
```

> A is a 10 × 30 matrix, B is a 30 × 5 matrix, and C is a 5 × 60 matrix. Then,
>   p[] = [10,30,5,60] i.e. Matrix Ai has dimension p[i-1] x p[i] for i = 1..n

This is what dynamic programming is all about. So we try all combinations of `k` and calculate `m[i,j]` but for that we also need to calculate `m[i,k]` and `m[k+1,j]` i.e. we break our problem down into smaller sub problems where the concept of chain length comes in.

So for all the matrices `A[i..n]` we calculate the most efficient way of multiplying a smaller chain of matrices of length `l`.

The smallest value of `l` is obviously 2 and the largest is `n` which is what we would get after we solve the smaller sub problems like I explained.

Let's come to the piece of code you are having trouble understanding:

```
 for l ← 2 to n                     //l is the chain length.
  do for i ← 1 to n − l + 1      
  do j ← i + l − 1        
  m[i, j] ← ∞
```

Now let's again consider a smaller example of 4 matrices `H,I,J,K` and you are looking at first chain lengths of 2. So when traversing the array of matrices.

```
 A[1..4] = H,I,J,K //where A[1] = H and A[4] = K
 For l = 2
 Our loop should go from i=1 to i=3, as for every i we are looking at the chain of length 2.

 So when i = 1, we would compute
 m[1,2] i.e. minimum cost to multiply chain (H,I)

 and when i = 3, we would compute
 m[3,4] i.e. minimum cost to multiply chain (J,K)
```

When chain length is 3, we would have:

```
  For i=1, j=3
  m[i,j] -> m[1,3] i.e. minimum cost to multiply chain (H,I,J)

  For i=2, j=4
  m[i,j] -> m[2,4] i.e. minimum cost to multiply chain (I,J,K)
```

Hence when we define `i` to not exceed `n-l+1` and `j=i+l-1`, we are making sure we are covering all the elements of the array and not exceeding the boundary condition i.e. the size of the array which is `n` and `j` defines the end of the chain starting from `i` with length `l`.

So the problem comes down to calculating `m[i,j]` for some `i` and `j` which as I explained earlier is solved by taking a partition `k` and trying out all possible values of `k` and then re-defining `m[i,j]` as the minimum value which is why it is initialized as `∞`.

I hope my answer wasn't too long and it gives you clarity as to how the algorithm flows and helps you appreciate the sheer vastness of dynamic programming.

Comment: Thank you. I appriciate your time and effort. :)

Comment: No worries @EsterVojkollari. Consider marking the answer as accepted so that others in a similar problem might also get some help. :)